# Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'NSIndexSet *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating an app but when i finished the code it says

Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'NSIndexSet *' is disallowed with ARC to this code

```
Cell.textLabel.text = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexPath.row];
```

how do i fix it? hope you can help Rasmus

Comment: I believe you wanted to use objectAtIndex: instead of objectsAtIndexes:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is that line supposed to do, [`objectsAtIndexes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJGGAAA) will return a array of objects match all the [`NSIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object wintin the [`NSIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that is passed as the parameter.

Try [`objectAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDJBFC) which will return the object at the index given.

```
Cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: @MartinR : No, it should be `indexPath.row`

Comment: @MidhunMP: You are right. My comment was nonsense and I have deleted it.

Comment: i now get this error message "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'objectsAtIndex:' "

Comment: @RasmusKirkebyBorup:`objectAtIndex` NOT `object*s*AtIndex`